# HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect() change method type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

just a short question - what method (e. g. GET, POST etc.) does sendRedirect use? Does it inherits it from request? And, if so, is it possible to change it to another?
Thanks!

Comment: The Javadocs could prove very useful. Did you look at them?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes have you seen there anything about the method which is used to make this redirect?

Comment: No I have not, but if you haven't looked, they're a great place to do so. If you have, of course, then my comment isn't applicable, but if you haven't, it's a good suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your comment :) Sure, I looked at javadocs first then tried googling but didn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sendRedirect sends a RESPONSE, not a REQUEST. And hence, has no METHOD.

It is up to the client, but it will normally do a GET or a HEAD request to the Location that you provide on the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response! Is my understanding correct - it just says browser "hey, go to this address!" and browser itself decides which method it would use? And it's all the same response or another one is created?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You will answer with a redirect, and the browser will initiate a new request to the provided Location.

Comment: Normally, it will make a HEAD or a GET - but you are in no control of which one. See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt for details.

Answer (score 2):

This matter is a little messy, see spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4

There are a bunch of redirect response codes - `300 301 302 303 307 308`. We can probably summarize the rules as the following:

1. by default, redirect does not change request method
2. 303 always changes the request method to GET (unless it's HEAD)
3. 301/302 changes POST to GET

to put it in a table ( "-" means the same method )

```
       300   301   302   303   307   308  
 HEAD   -     -     -     -     -     -
  GET   -     -     -     -     -     -
 POST   -    GET   GET   GET    -     -
other   -     -     -    GET    -     -
```

Browsers usually won't auto follow a redirect to POST.

In practice, 303 is the most often used code for web applications.